# How to force a column to stay within the user's view

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a header, left column, main column, and a footer. I want to be able to keep my left column always in the user's view no matter how far they scroll down etc.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

add `position: fixed` to your column css - http://jsfiddle.net/P99Ny/

Answer (score 1):

Apply `position: fixed;` in your CSS for the left column - that will always keep it in view. Use `top` and `left` also to set its position as per needs.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to supplement `position:fixed;` with [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/), a jQuery plugin. This is great if your left column has a lot of space between itself and the very top of your page. It's pretty easy to use as well.